# Distinguish union type with type parameter in Scala 3

Tags: scala, union-types, scala-3

In Scala 3, given such a type alias:

```scala
type Test[A] = A | Option[A]

val first: Test[String] = "gandalf"
val second: Test[String] = None
val third: Test[String] = Some("sam")
```

how can i distinguish which one of the two cases I have (`A` or `Option[A]`)?

When trying to write code, I think the main problem is that for the compiler and type, including `Either[String, B], matches` A`. I don't even know if there is an idiomatic solution for my problem.

This is my best attemp, any one other failed:

```scala
def get[A](input: Test[A]): A =
  input match
    case Some(value) => value.asInstanceOf[A]
    case None        => throw new RuntimeException("Error!")
    case _           => input.asInstanceOf[A]

get(first) // "gandalf"
get(second) // Exception!!!
get(third) // sam"
```

as you can see `value` is not recognized to be the same type as the type parameter `A` and the `A` case at the bottom can't really be checked at runtime (trying `case a: A =>` gives a compilation error) so I catch it by exclusion from the other two. This doesn't look like an optimal solution.

Comment: Union types are not tagged, that means they do not remember things like order and in runtime they are erased to `Any` and everything is done using class checks and casts. They are not a good tool for modelling, they are a handy tool for avoiding allocation in small places.

Comment: I think tagging is the magic word here. I think i was in the completely wrong direction

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `TypeTest`:

```
  def get[A](input: Test[A])(using tt: TypeTest[Any, A]): A =
    input match
      case a: A           => a
      case Some(value: A) => value
      case None           => throw new RuntimeException("Error!")
```